# Trying to find the ratio of male to female for each religion

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to find the ratio of male to female for each religion in India in Tableau.

E. g. if `Males = 2` and `Females = 3` then `male percent = 40` and `female percent = 60`.

I'm doing this for every religion.

I don't want to do this in Excel but to do it via some calculation in Tableau.
How can I do it ?

Here are the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewBAJ.png) and the [data source (Religion Data of India)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phfj2.png).

Note that in the image, the viz shows the total *numbers* of males and females and *not* the percentages.

Comment: correction done

Comment: Create a formula like sum(males)/sum(females). this will give the correct ratio at the level of aggregation used in the view (so, if you are looking at states, you will get the right ratio for each state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a table calculation. I assume you have a variable called `Value` that holds the number of females or males, and that your Tableau data is arranged as in the screenshot below.

1. Click on the SUM(Value) pill and choose `Add Table Calculation`
2. For `Calculation Type`, choose `Percent of Total`
3. For `Summarize the values from:`, choose `Pane (Across)`

[image]

Comment: Hi this was useful. Thanks a lot

Comment: If this solved your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the male to female ratio for each religion, irrespective of any other columns add a calculation
{Fixed religion : sum(male)/sum(female)}